# Failed to select the links inside <nav> tags and apply the javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, hyperlink

I am trying to apply this JS (http://jsfiddle.net/GNgjZ/) the links inside a `<nav></nav>`, or to say, **only apply the javascript to the links inside the `<nav></nav>`**
The problem is I cannot seem to select the links inside:

```
<nav id="menu" class="group"><ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-119" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-100 current_page_item menu-item-119">
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/">Home</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-118" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-118">
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/contact/">Contact</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-117" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-117">
    <a href="http://localhost/wordpress/people/">People</a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("nav").ready(function()
    {
        $("a").hover(function(e)
        {
            var randomClass = getRandomClass();
            $(e.target).attr("class", randomClass);
        });
    });
});

function getRandomClass()
{
    //Store available css classes
    var classes = new Array("green", "purple", "teal", "violet", "pink");

    //Give a random number from 0 to 5
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);

    return classes[randomNumber];
}
```

why is it not working? any solutions?

Comment: Remove `$("nav").ready..`. The DOM already loaded with the above ready handler. [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNgjZ/286/)

Comment: Are just trying to get your links to highlight when the user hovers over them?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/GNgjZ/288/ ? Your original fiddle did not have a returned value inside of `getRandomClass` function

Comment: Theoretically without that selector, all the links in my document would be selected by my javascript right? But, i only want links inside the `<nav></nav>`

Comment: Here's a fix to your first fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GNgjZ/289/

Comment: To select only links inside the nav: `$('nav a')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I fixed the code in your question to do what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('nav a').attr('class',getRandomClass());
});

function getRandomClass()
{
    //Store available css classes
    var classes = ['green', 'purple', 'teal', 'violet', 'pink'];

    //Give a random class index
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length);

    return classes[randomNumber];
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNgjZ/290/)